# Appropriate use of GROUP BY clause in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am beginner in oracle queries.
I am logging to the database as HR and acessing table Employees.

My query is like :

```
select department_id,min(avg(salary)) from employees.........
```

I want to display the result by grouping according to department_id without sub-queries,
and with sub-query.

Comment: What is your intended result. You have two aggregate functions. You can't do that. If your intended result is to _get the average salary of each department, and then get the department with minimum average salary_, you need a subquery.

Comment: If I were you I would've provided an initial script (`create table...; insert into ...` or just CTE `with t as (select ...) select * from t`) and created a table with the expected output based on the initial script.

Comment: this db i am using is a sample scheme in Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

```
select department_id, 
       min(salary) as min_sal, 
       max(salary) as max_sal,
       avg(salary) as avg_sal
from employees
group by department_id
```

Either take the minimum salary or the average for a single column, but you can't take both. Use seperate columns to get both.

Comment: OK, Thanks for reply. So sub-query is a MUST ??

Comment: It is unclear what you want to have. Both in the same column is not possible. But in seperate ones like in my answer I just updated.

Comment: I want in same column.

Comment: And how should that be calculated? What is a minimun-average salary? Do you want the department with the minimun average salary?